# Gm much lesser than it should be

Tags: transistors, simulation, device-characteristics

Assuming square law model, transconductance of an npn transistor in saturation mode can be found as gm = Kn'* (W/L) * (Vgs-Vth) which can also be written as gm=2*Id/(Vgs-Vth).
Now, while simulating a particular Si-technology file, I am using a very simple circuit (W/L=1), which I have attached. The DC analysis on LTSpice gives:

Id=1.58 uA , Vgs = .5 V, Vth = 0.469 V, and **gm = 2.73e-5**

However, 2*Id/(Vgs-Vth) is **10.19e-5** . Can someone please explain the discrepancy? Because the difference is too big to be attributed to non-ideal effects.

[image: The circuit I am using]

[The technology file I am using](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SWYSwaePN5UsaKR0RSGOG7tryQDh04ta/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think you may be confused about transistors. NPN transistors are bipolar. They do not have parameters named \$V_{th}\$ or \$V_{GS}\$. Those parameters belong to MOSFETs.

Comment: Your equation is valid only for operation in strong inversion. You operate between weak to moderate inversion. Try using a gate overdrive of 250 mV and see if gm is close to your calculation.